# Best way to store Gmail conversations in MySQL from the Google API (Indexes)

Tags: php, mysql, api, indexing, gmail

For those that have built an app using Gmail's API, I'd love to get your feedback on database structure for conversations.

Currently, my app looks at email addresses in my own DB and uses the `listmesssages`function to grab `ids` and then finds `user_messages`based on those ids.

Basically, it's looking to see if there were previous interactions with a specific contact.

I'd like to run this script in a cron job, but I'm having a difficult time deciding how to index these to avoid duplication.

The fields that I'm storing in MySQL from the Gmail API are:

```
    messageid
    thread id
    from name
    to name
    subject
    email date
    mime type
    body
```

I'd like to be able to periodically check (24 hours) to see if there were responses in the Gmail account until a project is marked as "complete."

Any ideas on how to index these to avoid duplication?

Comment: What combination of column(s) are unique?  I would guess `message_id`, and I would guess that that should be the `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: Thanks! Looked through my data and it appears as though message_id is the primary key. Thread ID is not unique.

Comment: How did you manage the Gmail login in cron job?